# Unable to complete due to service connection error - Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, user-controls, azure-ad-b2b

I was follwing the steps in the title "**Add an allow list**" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list
As listed in steps

1.Sign in to the Azure portal.

2.Select Azure Active Directory > Users > User settings.

3.Under External users, select Manage external collaboration settings.

I cannot perform the 3rd step, An error pops up like this
[image: Unable to complete due to service connection error - Azure AD]

what to do?

Comment: Similar questions:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b8a8b9a-48d7-4a44-8b9a-3f64d12e93f3/user-management-unable-to-complete-due-to-service-connection-error-please-try-again-later?forum=windowsazuremanagement

Comment: I checked that, but that's not a valid solution

Comment: I think this may be caused by the network. Please try another network and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely that this is a network issue, please try on another network or browser. If the issue persists please share the console log output.

Comment: I am getting POST https://graph.windows.net/isDirectoryFeatureEnabled?api-version=1.6-internal 400 (Bad Request) from E7MfroBJJdTJ.js:33 in the console and when I open the link i get this {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_InvalidRequestUrl","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Request url was invalid. The request should be like \/tenantdomainname\/Entity or \/$metadata. Tenant domain name can be any of the verified, unverified domain names or context id."}}}